# jquery selector how to selector two element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
<select name="d1">
  <option value="dd">111</option>
  <option value="dd">111111</option>
</select>
<select name="d2">
 <option value="dd">2222</option>
  <option value="dd">222222222222</option>
</select>
```

i have two select how two use jquery select this two

```
$("select[name='d1']").change(function(){xxx});
```

this code only could select one element,any one could give a hand,thanks

Comment: In worst-case you can always use the `add` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several options.

1. Select all select elements on the page:

   ```
   $("select").change(function(){xxx});
   ```
2. Select only those select elements contained within a form having the ID `formD`:

   ```
   $("form#formD select").change(function(){xxx});
   ```
3. Select only those select elements in class `d` (add a `class` HTML attribute to each select element):

   ```
   $("select.d").change(function(){xxx});
   ```
4. Select only those select elements whose names/IDs begin with `d`:

   ```
   $("select[name^=d]").change(function(){xxx});
   ```
5. Select only those select elements specifically named by ID (add an `id` HTML attribute to each select element):

   ```
   $("select#d1, select#d2").change(function(){xxx});
   ```
6. Select only those select elements specifically named using the `name` attribute (which I would try to avoid because it is less readable):

   ```
   $("select[name='d1'], select[name='d2']").change(function(){xxx});
   ```

Comment: +1 for showing all the ways to do it. I'd recommend option 3.

Comment: oh wait, he did too. +1 withdrawn.

Answer (score 3):

```
$("select[name='d1'],select[name='d2']").change(function(){xxx});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could select d1 or d2:

```
$("select[name='d1'], select[name='d2']").change(function(){xxx});
```

But it would be more elegant if you assigned them the same class and then selected based on that:

```
<select name="d1" class="d">...</select>
<select name="d2" class="d">...</select>

$("select.d").change(function(){xxx});
```

Answer (score 2):

`$("select[name^=d]")` - will return all `select`s with name beginning in `d`. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KjURE/ . This is exactly what you asked for